# close a mysqli connection: return?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am extending a class from mysqli, but I am not sure if I am doing correctly when I want to close the db connection:

```
class database extends mysqli
{
    public function __construct($hostname = null,$username= null,$password = null,$database = null,$port = null, $socket = null)
    {
        $hostname = $hostname !== null ? $hostname : ini_get("mysqli.default_host");
        $username = $username !== null ? $username : ini_get("mysqli.default_user");
        $password = $password !== null ? $password : ini_get("mysqli.default_pw");
        $database = $database !== null ? $database : "";
        $port     = $port     !== null ? $port     : ini_get("mysqli.default_port");
        $socket   = $socket   !== null ? $socket   : ini_get("mysqli.default_socket");

        parent::__construct($hostname,$username,$password,$database,$port,$socket);


        # Check for connection error

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
        {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
    }


    #closes the database connection when object is destroyed.
    public function __destruct()
    {
        return parent::close();
        //echo "Destructor Called";
    }
}
```

do I have put `return` in front of `parent::close();`?

```
return parent::close();
```

or this will do?

```
public function __destruct()
        {
            parent::close();

        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just an extra comment here; Using `exit` in a constructor (or any OO code for that matter) is generally a bad idea. Consider throwing an exception instead.

Comment: @ Phil Brown: thanks. I want to throw an exception but I don't how to throw and catch it in my db class... any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea with a destructor is that it is automatically called when the object goes out of scope. As such, there will be nothing to assign a return value to.

The best practice is for destructors (and constructors) to not return anything (void).

Program code should never call the destructor directly.

**Edit:** So to directly answer your question, use your second example

```
public function __destruct()
{
    parent::close();
}
```

---

Regarding exceptions, try something like this in your constructor

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    throw new Exception('Connect failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

To catch the exception, simply use a try / catch block, eg

```
try {
    $database = new database();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage(); // or whatever
}
```

Comment: @lauthiamkok Use your second example, leave out the `return` (see my edit above).